# Arithmoquine function in Gödel's proof

Tags: incompleteness

Could someone explain as detailed as possible how the Arithmoquine{a,a'} function works or is the defined in Gödel's proof of the incompleteness theorem?

To describe my question better...

In [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R_Va91Q0VK4) after 9:30 there is a definition of an Arithmoquine function, I didn't really understood it very well, could someone more knowledgeable explain it in more details?

Comment: Godel's theorem has been written a hundred times over in different notations. Define Arithmoquine{a,a'} or give a reference to the particular development you are following.

Comment: Sorry, I edited for more clarity

Comment: See Douglas Hofstadter, [Gödel  Escher Bach : An Eternal Golden Braid](https://books.google.it/books?id=yeu2AAAAIAAJ) (Basic Book ed. 1979), page 445.

Answer (score 1):

The ARITHMOQUINE function is defined with the $Subst$ function.

See [Gödel Numbering](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/sup1.html) for a similar function:

> $subst(x,y)=z$

and its use in [The Diagonalization Lemma](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/sup2.html).

In a nutshell, via the [Arithmetization of syntax](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/goedel-incompleteness/index.html#AriForLan) we are able to associate to every symbol, and thus to every formula (as a sequence of symbols) a number, its G-number, and this in an algorithmic way; i.e. for every formula we can compute its G-number and we can "unpack" a G-number to recover the corersponding formula.

Thus, given a *formula* $A(x)$ with *free* variable $x$, we can compute its G-number $\ulcorner A(x) \urcorner$ and given a *numeral* $\underline n$, i.e. a *term* of the language of arithmetic "naming" the *number* $n$, we can compute its G-number $\ulcorner \underline n \urcorner$.

The function :

> $subst(x, y) = z$

is a mathematical operation which maps the pair with the Gödel number of a formula with one free variable and the Gödel number of a numeral to the Gödel number of the closed formula which results from the original formula when the given numeral is substituted for the free variable:

> > $subst(\ulcorner A(x) \urcorner, \ulcorner \underline n \urcorner) = \ulcorner A(\underline n) \urcorner$.

In other words, the function ARITHMOQUINE compute the G-number corresponding to the *sentence* obtained from the *formula* $A(x)$ when the *term* "naming" the *number* $n$ is *substituted* into $A(x)$ in place of the *free* variable $x$.

---

*Example*: we can consider the formula $x= \underline 0$ and the *term* $S(\underline 0)$ "naming" the number $1$. The result of the substitution is the sentence:

> $S(\underline 0) = \underline 0$.

Comment: Did you meant $subst(\ulcorner A(x) \urcorner, \ulcorner n \urcorner) = \ulcorner A({\color{red} n}) \urcorner$?